# discord.py - mutliple messages posting - RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, runtime-error, discord.py

i want to create a Discord bot that send messages I enter in a console or generate with another piece of code (e.g. sensor data) to a channel.
I've tried with the following but after entering the second message I get a RuntimeError: Event loop is closed. Any suggestions?

```
import discord


def send_message(message):
    token = "mydiscordbottoken"
    channel_id = channelid
    bot = discord.Client()

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        await bot.get_channel(channel_id).send(message)
        await bot.close()

    bot.run(token)


while True:
    mes = input('Enter message: ')
    send_message(mes)
```

I want to get back into my while-loop outsite the fuction after printing the message.
When running the code I get the following error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000206ABBDC940>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000206ABBDC940>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/janik/PycharmProjects/learnpython/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    send_message(mes)
  File "C:/Users/janik/PycharmProjects/learnpython/main.py", line 14, in send_message
    bot.run(token)
  File "C:\Users\janik\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 695, in run
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(runner(), loop=loop)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 669, in ensure_future
    task = loop.create_task(coro_or_future)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 429, in create_task
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run.<locals>.runner' was never awaited
```

I'm kinda new to asycio and discord.py, just wanted to print out multiple messages to my discord server.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't quite properly set up your code correctly in that `input()` will freeze the code. Here is how I recommend you do it.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "PREFIX")

@client.command()
async def sendMessage(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, *, message):
    await channel.send(message)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

This makes it so you can do the command `(PREFIX)sendMessage (#CHANNEL) (MESSAGE)`. Since you're new I'll also explain the usage of the `*` in the command arguments. The `*` allows for our message to be multiple words long so that anything after the channel is included in the message.

If you have any more questions feel free to message me either on StackOverflow or on Discord at starmoan#4269!

Comment: Thank you very much! But my goal here is to achieve that I can input the message in my python cmd line that then starts the bot, send the entered message to a assigned channel and goes offline after that. This should be repetetive with e.g a while loop. Noone should be able to interact with the bot via discord chat

Comment: well, I solved my problem. I switched to a simple webhook which was exactly what I was looking for with _discord_webhook_ (https://pypi.org/project/discord-webhook/)

Comment: I'm so glad you found what you were looking for and I'm sorry that I didn't quite understand your problem!